# Working out the numbers of hours elapsed between two dates using datejs and timejs

Tags: javascript, datejs

I'm using the datejs library with timejs module. We receive contact requests into a table and want to work out our response times. So i have start date with timestamp and response date.

I used date.js to work out the time difference between the two dates. Problem is that it does a simple math calculation between the two numbers provided from each timestamp rather than taking into account that 24 hours elapse for each day difference.

So for example:

```
var start = Date.parse("Feb 16 2012 15:30:00"); 
var end = Date.parse("Feb 19 2012 09:30:00");

var span = new TimeSpan(end - start);

var tdiff = span.hours; 


console.log(tdiff);
```

This gives me a result of 18 hours, when the actual time elapsed between those two dates is 66hours. How can i use this library to give me the actual time elapsed?

Secondly, the working day is from 9am to 5.30pm, how can i exclude the hours that are not part of the working day from this calculation?

Comment: Just to clarify, the `TimeSpan` is made up of several time parts (days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds). Your `span` is returning `18 hours` because the difference between the `start` and `end` is `2 days and 18 hours`. You can calculate the total hours by multiplying the `days` by `24`, and adding the `hours`. Total Hours = `(2*24)+18=66`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = Date.parse("Feb 16 2012 15:30:00"); 
var end = Date.parse("Feb 19 2012 09:30:00");

var numOfHrs = (end-start) / (1000*60*60);
alert(numOfHrs);
alert((24-15.5) * (numOfHrs/24));
```

Comment: This doesnt answer my question. This code gives me an output of "0"

Comment: Thats weird. Im getting an output of "0" but i'll look into it.
Can you help me with how i might exclude the non-working hours?

Comment: @KhuramMalik : take a look at the code now. I've updated it to exclude non-working hours

Comment: OK - I see what you're doing here. So i could run an IF Statement right to check if the start or end date falls outside of the working hours bracket before i do the final calculation where i minus 15.5hours right?

Comment: I'm first excluding the non-working hours (15.5 hrs) from one day and then multiply it by total number of days

Comment: OK, but say a request comes in at 8pm one evening and we respond at 10am the next day. the total response time is 1 working hour - This doesnt solve that or does it? Do i not need to work out how many hours have elapsed from when the working day starts?

Comment: I didn't get your point. Doesn't the above code serve your requirement??